# Logging All Changes in Specific Format in Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Worksheet with Name STOCKS that auto updates for Stock Quotes Like Stock Name,Time,Last Rate Traded,Bid Rate,Ask Rate, etc.

```
Stock Name | Time | Last Trade Rate | Bid Price | Offer Price
1 ACC      | 10.40am| 42            | 41        | 43
2 INFY     | 10.40am| 100           | 99        | 101
3 TECH     | 10.40am| 140           | 136       | 142
```

The Prices and other all Row values for Each Stock keeps changing every second and is auto updated as and when price changes or bid, offer changes.

I Have add a separate Work Sheet named LOGSSHEET

What is want Excel Code to do:

If any Cell Value in any Column Changes then i want Log the Same in LOGSHEET where Entire COLUMN is Copied/Logged

For Example if Bid Price for INFY Stock Changes then Entire ROW (In this Case Row containing Stock INFY) should be logged/copied in LOGSHEET

Example:
2 INFY     | 10.40am| 100           | 99        | 101

Similarly if say Offer Price or Time or Last Trade Rate Changes for another or Same Script then it show be pasted/logged below the earlier logged entry Like:

```
2 INFY     | 10.40am| 100           | 99.10        | 101
3 TECH     | 10.40am| 140.50           | 136       | 142
```

Etc...

I am not much of Excel VBA programmer but I found this code that logs something but not entire row as organized.

I Found a Code that does something similar in an unorganized way, but not exactly what i want

Sample Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim strAddress As String
    Dim val
    Dim dtmTime As Date
    Dim Rw As Long

    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:M1000")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
       'change range to suit
    dtmTime = Now()
    val = Target.Value
    strAddress = Target.Address


    Rw = Sheets("Log Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With Sheets("Log Sheet")
        .Cells(Rw, 1) = strAddress
        .Cells(Rw, 2) = val
        .Cells(Rw, 3) = dtmTime
        .Cells(Rw, 3) = Stocks
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So you just want to copy the row which changed to the `Log Sheet`adding a column called what... `Time Stamp`? where you input the moment of the change?

Comment: Adding seperate time stamp too is not required....simply copy the entire row even if any one value in any of cells in that row changes .... so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do that:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Rw As Long

    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:M1000")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log Sheet")
        Rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Me.Rows(Target.Row).Copy .Cells(Rw, 1)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi what will happen if 2 values simultaneously change in same column - will it paste 2 time or only once....desired is only once

Comment: When you are talking about column you mean row, right??

Comment: And yes, if two values are changed simultaneously on the same row there will be only 1 paste.

Comment: Just Tested, It is Creating Multiple entries for simultaneous changes in same row, instead of one entry sir

Comment: This means they are not simultaneous... If you want only one row per row on your main sheet can be changed, but when you copy paste modifying 2 cells on the same row there will be only one entry with this code. So the script udpates first once cell, then the another.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the below code into the STOCKS worksheet module. This will copy across the row if a cell value changes within it (not tested).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim lRowLogSheet As Long

    'adjust the below target range to suit your needs
    If Intersect(Target, Range("C4:C8")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'find the last row in the log sheet
    lRowLogSheet = Sheets("LOGSSHEET").Range("A" & Sheets("LOGSSHEET").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'set the values of the row
    Sheets("LOGSSHEET").Range("A" & lRowLogSheet, "E" & lRowLogSheet).Value = Sheets("STOCKS").Range("A" & Target.Row, "E" & Target.Row).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Just Tested, it is creating Multiple Entries...for Eg if 3 Different value change within same row simultaneously then it is creating 3 entries.

Comment: @vinayagarwal You're welcome. Please mark as this as the answer to close the thread. Thanks.